# How to mute microphone using command line in debian 8?

Tags: debian, alsa

I use a Lenovo T420. It has mute mic button, but it cannot be assigned to any action, because I got error "The key you just pressed is not supported by Qt" when I'm trying to assign to any action. The ThinkVantage button can be assigned to an action, and I want to assign it to mute the mic.
I tried everything to make mic mute via command line, but nothing worked for me. For example, I tried these commands, the most helpful for other users, but didn't work for me:

```
root@qet-PC: /home/qet# amixer sset 'Internal Mic',0 mute
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied
amixer: Mixer attach default error: Connection refused

root@qet-PC: /home/qet# amixer set Capture toggle
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied
amixer: Mixer attach default error: Connection refused

root@qet-PC: /home/qet# amixer -c 0 sset Mic toggle
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Mic',0
```

results of **/proc/asound/cards** and **lspci | grep Audio**:

```
root@qet-PC: /home/qet# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf2520000 irq 47
29 [ThinkPadEC     ]: ThinkPad EC - ThinkPad Console Audio Control
                      ThinkPad Console Audio Control at EC reg 0x30, fw unknown
root@qet-PC: /home/qet# lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

How do I mute mic using command line, which I can assign to the ThinkVantage button in "System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures"?
Or maybe there is another way to mute mic pressing that button?

**UPDATE:**

Turns out it does not work when I run the command as root.
With user permissions, it works fine -- mic is muted, except I still get some errors in the terminal:

```
qet@qet-PC:~$ amixer set Capture toggle
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 80 [100%] [6.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 80 [100%] [6.00dB] [off]
qet@qet-PC:~$ amixer set Capture toggle
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Operation not permitted
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 80 [100%] [6.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 80 [100%] [6.00dB] [on]
```

Comment: Try alsamixer. That is not a command line tool but a very nice curses based terminal client. Your amixer seems to need some X server.

Answer (score 4):

On my system I get

```
amixer -c MID sget Capture
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 46
  Front Left: Capture 42 [91%] [25.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 42 [91%] [25.00dB] [on]

amixer -c MID sset Capture 23
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 46
  Front Left: Capture 23 [50%] [6.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 23 [50%] [6.00dB] [on]
```

That should control the mic volume. Check the alsamixer `F4` Capture Frontend for other settings that effect Mic Volume, such as Digital and Mic Boost.

Read the output of

```
amixer scontrols
```

for names of simple controls. The finer grained controls are given by the whole identifier:

```
amixer contents|grep -i cap
amixer cget numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
amixer cset numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch' off
```

The last disables the Capture completely. With the `alsamixer` command you can debug your `amixer` operations.

Answer (score 0):

KDE-specific answer, coming late, but for the record: On KDE, users may prefer to use Kmix via qdbus.

```
$ qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kmix invokeShortcut "mic_mute"
```

This will actually toggle the microphone.
([Source](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_Connect/Tutorials/Useful_commands))